# PhP, Parse Json Element, Not in array

Tags: php

I have following string. I need to extract just the Model: or the Orientaiton, or the Software and store as a variable. The problem I'm having is I don't know how to get individual variables. Any advice?

```
Model:  NIKON D200
Orientation:    0 
Resolution: 300.000 
ResolutionUnit: 2 
Software:   Nikon View 6.2.7 M
Date and Time:  2007:02:16 14:41:53
Exposure Time:  1/640 Sec
ISO Speed:  210
F Number:   8.0
Flash:  Yes, Strobe detected
Zoom Length:    32 mm
Exposure Program:   Manual
ISO Speed:  200 
Exposure Bias:  0.000 
Metering Mode:  Spot
Light Source:   Unknown
Zoom Length:    32 mm
```

Comment: `explode` on each line, then for each line `explode` on the first colon (ie. explode on colon, limit 2). Trim both sides, and use a `foreach` to find the "key" you want.

Comment: What you have there is not JSON. Please post the actual JSON data so we can better understand exactly what is needed to get the data you want.

Comment: @winterblood OP clearly stated that it's not JSON.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol To quote the question: "I have the following output in json".

Comment: @winterblood I fixed. I'm able to get everything as individual if it's an array, but not at ExifCamerainfo

Comment: See what you've done? Now we have a giant block of code that doesn't help at all because the original piece was plenty enough to answer the problem.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I've attached all output.

Comment: @user2600095 Please put it back how it was before. Your question was a lot easier to understand because you had (correctly) put only the *relevant* information.

Comment: Looks like `ExifCameraInfo` is just a big blob of string data. See the first comment above.

Comment: @Phil, how would i extract elements of string then?

Comment: Like I said, see @NiettheDarkAbsol's [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558815/php-parse-json-element-not-in-array#comment30747649_20558815) above

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I don't understand your first comment. Can you clarify? It's confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple function to do the conversion to an associative array.

```
// Convert a series of key:value lines to an associative array
function KeyValueLinesToAssocArray($lines) {
    $linesArray = explode("\n", $lines);
    print("Entries: " . count($linesArray) . "<br />");
    $assoc = array();
    foreach ($linesArray as $kv) {
        $kvs = explode(":", $kv, 2);
        if (2>count($kvs)) continue;
        $assoc[trim($kvs[0])] = trim($kvs[1]);
    }
    return $assoc;
}

$data = <<<DATA
Model:  NIKON D200
Orientation:    0 
Resolution: 300.000 
ResolutionUnit: 2 
Software:   Nikon View 6.2.7 M
Date and Time:  2007:02:16 14:41:53
Exposure Time:  1/640 Sec
ISO Speed:  210
F Number:   8.0
Flash:  Yes, Strobe detected
Zoom Length:    32 mm
Exposure Program:   Manual
ISO Speed:  200 
Exposure Bias:  0.000 
Metering Mode:  Spot
Light Source:   Unknown
Zoom Length:    32 mm
DATA;

// Now split the ExifCameraInfo string into an associative array
$exif = KeyValueLinesToAssocArray($data);

print $exif["Model"];
```

Comment: I got that far; I want only the model or the orientation, etc. your solution prints out entire string, whereas I only want a single element.
$camera =  $decoded[0][IPTC]['ExifCameraInfo'];

Comment: Ah, nice of you to downvote when your question is so vague. But easily fixed: split the string by newlines, break on first colon, then extract the appropriate values.

Comment: Lol, no worries - somebody did! I think we're moving in different directions as you edit your post and I my answer ;-)

Comment: your above answer works great for the data variable you define above....for what i have it doesn't work for some reason...??

Comment: Umm... I copied the data from your question above. Modify the function to : `    function KeyValueLinesToAssocArray($lines) {
        $linesArray = explode("\n", $lines);
        print("Entries: " . count($linesArray) . "<br />");` - see modification in code above. What does it print?